# Couting duplicate data in total for excel

Tags: excel, count, duplicates

```
      A            B
1     8     Tiffney, Jennifer
2     8     Tiffney, Jennifer
3     8     Tiffney, Jennifer
4     8     Tiffney, Jennifer
5     8     Tiffney, Jennifer
6     8     Tiffney, Jennifer
7     9     Allen, Larry
8     9     Allen, Larry
9     9     Allen, Larry
10    9     Allen, Larry
11    9     Allen, Larry
12    10    Reid, Brian
13    10    Reid, Brian
14    10    Reid, Brian
15    10    Reid, Brian
16    10    Reid, Brian
17    10    Reid, Brian
18    10    Reid, Brian
19    10    Reid, Brian
20    10    Reid, Brian
21    10    Reid, Brian
22    10    Reid, Brian
23    11    Edington, Bruce
24    11    Edington, Bruce
25    11    Edington, Bruce
26    12    Almond, David
27    12    Almond, David
28    12    Almond, David
29    12    Almond, David
30    12    Almond, David
31    12    Almond, David
32    13    Mittal, Charu
33    13    Mittal, Charu
34    13    Mittal, Charu
35    13    Mittal, Charu
36    13    Mittal, Charu
37    13    Mittal, Charu
```

There are tons of duplicate data in excel, Is there any way can count how many people will in total? I tried to use "Count" and "Countif" formulas, but there are duplicate data.

there should be 6 people in total as above, any solution to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following formula:

```
=COUNT(IF(FREQUENCY(MATCH(A1:A37,A1:A37,0),MATCH(A1:A37,A1:A37,0))>0,1))
```

or

In the EXCEL, click Data Tab. You will find Remove Duplicates. Select your column and click remove duplicates and all the duplicates will be removed. Now you have distinct data and you will get only 6 records

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF($A$1:$A$100,$A$1:$A$100))
```

Where $A$1:$A$100 is your data range.

Comment: @Isaac.H now you have the problem of choosing one as the correct answer.  Choose the one that you end up using, neither will have their feelings hurt if the other is chosen.